# javascript checkbox line-through

Tags: javascript, list, checkbox

I am trying to do a school project. I have to make a list and after the checkbox is clicked supposed to be crossed off. I don't know Javascript yet and I'm still trying to figure it out. I am wondering why this isn't working.

```js
function  crossout(id) {
  var box = document.getElementById(id);
  box.style = "text-decoration: line-through";
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <h3>Shopping List</h3>
    <p id="box1">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="crossout"("box1") />
      Banana
    </p>
    <p id="box2">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="crossout"("box2") />
      Noodles
    </p>
    <p id="box3">
      <input type="checkbox" onclick="crossout"("box3") />
      Eggs
    </p>

    <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
```

Comment: [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your checkboxes:

```
onclick="crossout"("box1")
```

This should be:

```
onclick="crossout('box1')"
```

Your original way set `onclick` only to `"crossout"`.

Comment: Thank you. My teacher taught me that yesterday. I didn't realize your supposed to quote the entire function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding events strictly inside the DOM, I would suggest you to catch every `checkbox` element, then iterate over it using `Array#forEach` and bind an `eventListener` to each of them. If you will check the `checkbox`, `checked` class will be applied to it's parent - `p` element.

It looks fine and works even better.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('change', function(){
      this.parentNode.classList.toggle('checked');
    }));
```

```css
.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<h3>Shopping List</h3>
<p id="box1">
  <input type="checkbox" class='box'>Banana
</p>
<p id="box2">
  <input type="checkbox" class='box'>Noodles
</p>
<p id="box3">
  <input type="checkbox" class='box'>Eggs
</p>
```

Comment: Ideally, I would agree. However as a first assignment when learning JavaScript in a school course, this is a little "advanced".

Comment: @krillgar Your solution fits more the OP expecations, however maybe it's better to take a step further ((: It's just an *extra feature* from me.

Comment: I used run code Snippet. It works in there but when I put it into my site. I saved it. Then I tried previewing it in browser for some odd reason its not working. I am using chrome.

Comment: @Kinduser agreed. For future visitors, I would definitely recommend your answer. However, where OP is at, keep it simple. I'd liken this to teaching a first grade child 4 x 4 = 16 when they're working on the problem 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 = 16.

Comment: @krillgar Agreed (: